# need to keep check the type of authenticatin for the flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have implemented firebase authentication for flutter app with email/password and google sign in, sign in is running successfully for both types and sign out for email/password.

I have one button to sign out, how should I keep check whether the sign in was google sign in or email/password so that I can process the respective sign out for the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every [User](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User-class.html) object has a [providerData](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/providerData.html) array - each [UserInfo](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth_platform_interface/latest/firebase_auth_platform_interface/UserInfo-class.html) element in that array represents one auth provider for that account (such as Google or email/password).  Before signing out, simply iterate that array and check the [providerId](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth_platform_interface/latest/firebase_auth_platform_interface/UserInfo/providerId.html) of the UserInfo to find out what the user was using to sign in.  You will have to reverse engineer the provider IDs unless you can find a list of them elsewhere.